# Im having trouble staying in the loop the total is also supposed to add till the user exits the loop with an input of N || n

Tags: c++, do-while

I cant seem to get my do while loop right, I am trying to make a program that takes an order asks if there are anymore orders and if there are then it will restart the loop and keep track of the total.
If the user picks N then the program exits and prints the total in full. The tax rate and zip codes will come into play latter I really just need some help with the loop part.

```
//menue for berry shop

#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

double a = 12.50, b = 19.99, c = 18.50, d = 35.00, e = 18.50,f = 35.00, totalprice;
const double TAX = 0.13;
char choice;
char answer;

do
{

    cout << "Fancy Fruits is pleased to provide Giant Strawberries for you today!";
    cout << "Your sales associate will be Phillip Ray " << endl;
    cout << ""<< endl;
    cout << "We deliver to these zipcodes"<< endl;
    cout << "----------------------------"<< endl;
            cout << "37918     37919" << endl;
            cout << "37920     37921" << endl;
            cout << "37922     37924" << endl;

    cout << "         Menu                                     Price "<< endl;
    cout << "         ----                                     ----- " <<endl;
    cout << "A:1 Dozen plain strawberries                      $" << a << endl;
    cout << "B:2 Dozen plain strawberries                      $" << b << endl;
    cout << "C:1 dozen choclate covered strawberries           $" << c << endl;
    cout << "D:2 Dozen choclate covered strawberries           $" << d << endl;
    cout << "E:1 Dozen dark choclate covered strawberries      $" << e << endl;
    cout << "F:2 Dozen dark choclate covered strawberries      $" << f << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    cout << "Are there any addtional orders? 'Y' or 'N'" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')

    {   //Display Choice

        cout << "Your choice?" << endl;
    }


     if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a')
     {

        cout << "A: One dozen plain strawberries" << a << endl;

     break;
    }


    if (choice == 'B' || choice == 'b')
    {

        cout << "B: Two dozen plain strawberries" << b << endl;
     break;
    }


  if (choice == 'C' || choice == 'c')
    {

        cout << "C:1 dozen choclate covered strawberries" << c << endl;
     break;
    }

 if (choice == 'D' || choice == 'd')
    {

        cout << "D: 2 dozen choclate covered strawberries " << d << endl;
     break;
    }


    if (choice == 'E' || choice == 'e')
    {

        cout << "E:1 dozen dark choclate covered strawberries " << e << endl;
     break;
    }
   

   if (choice == 'F' || choice == 'f')
            {

       cout << "F: 2 dozen dark choclate covered strawberries" << f << endl;
     break;
    }


       else if (answer == 'N' || answer == 'n')
    {
        cin >>  answer;

        cout << "The final bill for today is ";
        cout << totalprice <<endl;
    }

    else //Displaying error message
    {
        cout << "Invalid input";
}} 
while (answer != 'N' && answer != 'n');
{ (choice += totalprice);
}
return(0);  
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are observing? What behavior are you expecting and what are you getting instead?

Comment: The `break` statements are not correctly placed, they will exit the while loop.
In the `else if` statement, why is `answer` read? When `y` is given, what is the expected behavior of the menu? As it is now, it just prints "Your choice?". What is the purpose of `choice += totalprice`? `choice` is a character, and `totalprice` should be the variable accumulating the prices. Also, the latter accumulation is happening outside of the `do-while` loop. Finally, consider a `switch` statement, you can avoid the use of many `if` statements.

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example, so basically keep removing things that are unrelated until you arrive at small snippet that works different than you would have expected it. Chances are you will have figured out the problem yourself by then. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems. I'm assuming that you want this behavior:

1. Show the menu
2. Ask "your choice?"
3. Wait for the user to choose one of the options
4. Ask the user if he wants to order anything else
5. If the user answers "Y", go to step 2
6. If the user answers "N", get out of the while loop and proceed with the program.

If my understanding is correct, the first problem is that you are using `break` after printing out the choice of the user. Remember that `break` exits out of the do-while loop. The second problem is that the whole flow of the do-while loop seems wrong.

This code produces the output that I assume is what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a = 12.50, b = 19.99, c = 18.50, d = 35.00, e = 18.50,f = 35.00, totalprice = 0;
    const double TAX = 0.13;
    char choice;
    char answer;

    cout << "Fancy Fruits is pleased to provide Giant Strawberries for you today!";
    cout << "Your sales associate will be Phillip Ray " << endl;
    cout << ""<< endl;
    cout << "We deliver to these zipcodes"<< endl;
    cout << "----------------------------"<< endl;
    cout << "37918     37919" << endl;
    cout << "37920     37921" << endl;
    cout << "37922     37924" << endl;
    cout << "         Menu                                     Price "<< endl;
    cout << "         ----                                     ----- " <<endl;
    cout << "A:1 Dozen plain strawberries                      $" << a << endl;
    cout << "B:2 Dozen plain strawberries                      $" << b << endl;
    cout << "C:1 dozen choclate covered strawberries           $" << c << endl;
    cout << "D:2 Dozen choclate covered strawberries           $" << d << endl;
    cout << "E:1 Dozen dark choclate covered strawberries      $" << e << endl;
    cout << "F:2 Dozen dark choclate covered strawberries      $" << f << endl;
    do
    {
        cin >> choice;

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            cout << "A: One dozen plain strawberries " << a << endl;
            totalprice += a;
            break;
        case 'B':
        case 'b':
            cout << "B: Two dozen plain strawberries " << b << endl;
            totalprice += b;
            break;
        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            cout << "C:1 dozen choclate covered strawberries " << c << endl;
            totalprice += c;
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'd':
            cout << "D: 2 dozen choclate covered strawberries " << d << endl;
            totalprice += d;
            break;
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
            cout << "E:1 dozen dark choclate covered strawberries " << e << endl;
            totalprice += e;
            break;
        case 'F':
        case 'f':
            cout << "F: 2 dozen dark choclate covered strawberries" << f << endl;
            totalprice += f;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid input\n";
        }
        cout << "Are there any addtional orders? 'Y' or 'N'" << endl;
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {   //Display Choice
            cout << "Your choice?" << endl;
        }
    } while (answer != 'N' && answer != 'n');
    cout << "The final bill for today is " << totalprice <<endl;
    return(0);
}
```

I used a `switch-case` scheme instead of the `if` chain because it looks better. I also recommend you:

- Work on indentation. Your code is much easier to read and understand when you have consistent indentation.
- Use more significative variable names, not `a`, `b` and the sorts.
- Consider using more C++ features, especially the STL, as your program is basically a C program that uses `cin` and `cout` instead of `printf` and `scanf`.

Perhaps it would be a good idea to look up a code-style guide and try to follow it.